# Namecheap webmail setup but can't receive email

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53, namecheap

I'm trying to setup incoming email for my Amazon EC2 linux box. Namecheap Private Email records for domains with third-party DNS
My domain's DNS is managed through NameCheap. They have a private email hosting service.

https://www.namecheap.com/hosting/email.aspx

Will this enable me to have a webmail interface where I can send / receive emails from my domain?

Comment: So what are you trying to achieve Name Cheap Email box to work or some thing else, your question is little confusing?

Comment: I am trying to update MX in aws server.i able to send mail but i did't receive email.

Comment: Did you contact name cheap support asking them why you are not able to get incoming emails?

Comment: Yes,i had word with namecheap support and he tell us to kindly update MX to amazon aws server.I have also updated MX to Route 53,but i did't resolve problem.and after also talk with namecheap support he tell us kindly contact to Amzon AWS support team.

Comment: What is the Domain?

Comment: My domain name is http://www.mytapptalk.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I checked your domain and it does not have any MX Records setup. See screenshot below. That is the reason you are not receiving the emails.

[image]

Check this steps to set up MX Records for AWS Route 53 for your domain

https://support.google.com/a/answer/6149697?hl=en

Comment: Thanks for guide.Let me check and update you soon.

Comment: This was helpful for me in setting up Namecheap email account with DigitalOcean. This guide was also helpful - https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/1340/2176/namecheap-private-email-records-for-domains-with-thirdparty-dns/